# GUI not showing up on running the main project in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, netbeans-7

I made a swing GUI using net beans, When I run the main project, the GUI is not showing up. But the output window shows the build successful.Run file is working ok.  What might be wrong ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you don't show us the code, we can't really help you all that much. Remember we don't see your code, so it's hard to guess what's going on.

Comment: It's very hard to answer this question in it's current state as there can be several reasons. setVisible() can be false, the initGui (if it exists) might never be called, or if you have a "mainpanel" it might not be added the right way etc etc. Please post some relevant code from the constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just guessing here, but do you actually create an instance of the GUI and then set it visible somewhere in a method, for example, your main() method?

For example

```
MyGuiClass app = new MyGuiClass();
app.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: my GUI app has setvisible=TRUE but app not showing up